# Passing Sensitive Information Via SignalR

Tags: security, signalr

Would it ever be wise to pass along more sensitive information using SignalR for your application to process. I've been thinking about this for a while now as part of a concept for a personal project and I can't think of any drawbacks. However I don't know that much about SignalR and I'd like to know for sure if this would have any flaws security-wise. I understand there are plenty of other accepted methods for passing secure data to the client, but I want to focus specifically on SignalR.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security

Comment: Very informational and much appreciated, thanks!